# Query an object referencing a collection field and another field from it's embedded collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, embedded-documents

I have a User collection with an embedded Address collection. I want to find or initialize a document with user email and embedded document address' field zipcode. Both these queries return the user object independently.

```
User.find_or_initialize_by(email: "contact@yahoo.com")
User.find_or_initialize_by("address.zipcode": "14421")
```

However, the following query does not return an object

```
User.find_or_initialize_by(email: "contact@yahoo.com", "address.zipcode": "14421")
```

I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
User.all_of({:'address.zipcode' => '14421'}, {:email => 'cantact@yahoo.com'})
```

Hope that helps!